# Open file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Can any one tell me, how can i able to open swf file , .rm file , .wmv file in iPhone?
Please give me a proper details about this or any sample code would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash + iOS ... hmm, do they support it? : 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2594709?start=0&tstart=0

EDIT:
Same for WMV files, windows media is not supported: http://discussions.apple.com/thread/3062941?start=0&tstart=0

I assume also Real Media will keep their format (.rm files). Sorry.

Here is "Steve Jobs`s comment" on this question: http://apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash . One thing to mention for his comment... flash IS touch enabled now :)

Comment: Can you explain here about your given link, what is the result behind this?

Comment: Thanks, and is it passible to open the swf file in UIWebview?

Comment: I`m afraid it wont suport flash as it is a wrapper of webkit. I would not suggest to use it. Also when searched in web I found this article, where most ot the pros and cons are presented: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/uiwebview-must-die/